# How to get a mix-blend-mode changing color effect but selecting the colors?

Tags: css, darkmode, mix-blend-mode

In the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kr57n7?file=testing.css) (here is the [demo](https://js-kr57n7.stackblitz.io)), when clicking the circle on the top right, you'll see a circle expanding and changing the colors of the background and text and also making a square appear. I think this effect is pretty cool, I love the fact that the circle changes the text color as it goes through.

I was wondering if there is any approach to achieving this same effect but being able to select the  colors for each mode. I have selected the "dark mode" colors but the brighter colors are automatically created based on whatever the `mix-blend-mode: difference` is doing.

Also, the appearing square is using `mix-blen-mode: brighter` I just found this after playing around. This is cool and all but I'd like to be able to use whatever colors I want for both modes.

I tried using clip-path is some way but it's been hell, I am just not aquinted with CSS enough to even start thinking of another way to do so. I would love some push in the right direction or a link to a pen/stakblitz achieving this effect. Sadly every example uses just black and white.

```js
let modeToggle = document.querySelector('.mode-toggle');
let darkMode = document.querySelector('.dark-mode');

modeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode.classList.toggle('active');
  modeToggle.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS',
    'sans-serif';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

/*Button that changes mode*/
.mode-toggle {
  background-color: #db3069;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 20;
  transition: 1000ms all;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* This contains the expanding background inside the button */
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

/* This is the expanding background */
.dark-mode {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(0);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #161616;
  transition: 3000ms ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

/* This is the big pink box, I'd like these to be different things around the page that would hold no content but appear only on dark mode */
.content-to-appear {
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #db3069;
}

.dark-mode.active {
  transform: scale(1);
}

 /* This makes things change color in respect to the background */
.mode-toggle,
h1,
p {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

h1 {
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: #db3069;
}

p {
  color: #9aa0de;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mode-toggle"></div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dark-mode"></div>
    </div>

    <p class="content-to-appear"></p>

    

      <div class="hero">

        <h1>LOREM IPSUM LOREM LOREM LOREM</h1>
        <p class="test">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>


      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please could you make a runnable snippet (so your question makes sense to future readers when that external site disappears). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth You are correct, I should do so. I'm on it

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of CSS variables to set globally controlled items, like colors and mix-blend-mode, create HTML inputs that can be changed for these values, and then add JS listeners that will change the CSS Variable based on the input change.

```js
let modeToggle = document.querySelector('.mode-toggle');
let darkMode = document.querySelector('.dark-mode');

modeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode.classList.toggle('active');
  modeToggle.classList.toggle('active');
});

// Access :root to adjust CSS variables
let r = document.querySelector(':root');

// Toggle Color picker input listener
let toggleColorPicker = document.querySelector('#toggle-color');

toggleColorPicker.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let newColor = toggleColorPicker.value
  
  r.style.setProperty('--toggle-color', newColor);
})

// Mix-blend-mode input listener
let toggleBlendMode = document.querySelector('#toggle-blend-mode');

toggleBlendMode.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let newBlendMode = toggleBlendMode.value
  
  r.style.setProperty('--blend-mode', newBlendMode);
})
```

```css
:root {
  --toggle-color: #db3069;
  --blend-mode: difference;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', 'sans-serif';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}


/*Button that changes mode*/
.mode-toggle {
  background-color: var(--toggle-color);
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 20;
  transition: 1000ms all;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* This contains the expanding background inside the button */

.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}


/* This is the expanding background */

.dark-mode {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(0);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #161616;
  transition: 3000ms ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}


/* This is the big pink box, I'd like these to be different things around the page that would hold no content but appear only on dark mode */

.content-to-appear {
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: var(--toggle-color);
}

.dark-mode.active {
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* This makes things change color in respect to the background */

.mode-toggle,
h1,
p {
  mix-blend-mode: var(--blend-mode);
}

h1 {
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: var(--toggle-color);
}

p {
  color: #9aa0de;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Color picker -->
  <div>
    <label for="toggle-color">Select the new toggle color:</label>
    <input type="color" id="toggle-color" name="toggle-color" value="#db3069">
  </div>
  <!-- END Color picker -->
  
  
  <!-- Mix-blend-mode picker -->
  <div>
    <label for="toggle-blend-mode">Select the new mix-blend-mode:</label>
    <select name="toggle-blend-mode" id="toggle-blend-mode">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="normal">Normal</option>
      <option value="hard-light">Hard-light</option>
      <option value="difference">Difference</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END Mix-blend-mode picker -->

  <button class="mode-toggle"></button>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="dark-mode"></div>
  </div>

  <p class="content-to-appear"></p>

  <div class="hero">
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM LOREM LOREM LOREM</h1>
    <p class="test">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see how this lets the user choose the colors (not just the one color). Is there a way?

Comment: I meant to let the developer use the different colors, choosing whatever colors he want for the dark and light mode.

I changed the description a bit to show this

Comment: @JoaquinLeimeter I suppose It would depend on which `mix-blend-mode` chosen. with `difference` it is pretty straightforward because it's just going to be the inverse hex color, but I'm unsure how the browser determines other `mix-blend-mode` changes, like `hard-light` for example. They may not be possible to determine